# In PIC microcontroller can i use USART as UART

Tags: pic

Can I use USART of PIC microcontroller as UART ? How ?

Comment: Did you try disabling synchronous mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes.  I think there's a bit of a terminology mixup here.  A better name for the USART might be "Universal Synchronous/Asynchronous Receiver/Transmitter", which is to say, you have a choice of using it in either synchronous or asynchronous mode.  The way to do this is to find the configuration registers for that peripheral, and set them appropriately.  Refer to the data sheet, because where you set them depends on which PIC you choose.